# how to insert a numpy array having only one element to mysql db?

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, numpy

i am having a python program which has got a numpy array with a single element say a=['this is the element']
i need to insert this value to my database(MySQL).

i used execute() but it is showing an attribute error

my sql part to select data from table is this :

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
mysql_cn=mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                              host='127.0.0.1',port='3388',
                              database='proj')

X = pd.read_sql('select stamp from test;', con=mysql_cn)
mysql_cn.close()
```

so what has to be done since mysql_cn.execute() is not working?
i also tried pd.to_sql but it is also not working

this is the error for execute()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\data\test.py", line 132, in <module>
    haa=mysql_cn.execute('select stamp from test;')// this is my simple query not my actual query
AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: when i use mysql_cn.execute() i am getting an attribute error saying execute is not an attribute

Comment: because execute requires the query as a parameter.

Comment: actually i skipped the query while commenting.. i tried with query.. but even if i have a query its showing attribute error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cursor. You have to create a cursor from your mysql_cn then you can call execute on the cursor.

```
cursor = mysql_cn.cursor()
# Now call cursor.execute ....
```